# Different file extension for \input files?

Tags: external-files

Is there a conventional choice for a different file-extension given to source files prepared for `\input` (i.e. containing LateX source, but not something you can process on its own)?

---

The context here is automatically packing up selected files (including documentation written in LaTeX) from a medium-sized software project for sharing with a third-party.

I run a test build on the software that automatically identifies source files and this has saved me from shipping incomplete packages already.

Now I find that I have to include much more documentation than I was previosuly shipping and I'd like to test-build this as well. But simple file-name (`DOC_SOURCES!=ls *.tex`) globbing picks up the `\input` files as well as the master files. So currently I've hand-tooled the test-build, but that is fragile.

This is solvable if I give the `\input` files a different extension. (Alas `.texi` is already used by tex-info files.)

---

I noticed the [`flatex` tool](https://github.com/johnjosephhorton/flatex) and could do something like that as an alternative (my users don't need to code organized for convenient editting, afterall), but my fellow developer might not appreciate my adding a tools to the required build environment that they can't get from the package manager...

Comment: Aha! Turns out latexpand is available in our package manager, so I have solved the immediate problem by flattening the source files for inclusion.

Comment: Note that `\include` requires that the argument has *no* extension and called file *must* have extension `.tex`.

Comment: Hmmm ... yes. I guess the question should be restricted to `\input`. Thanks.

Comment: You can use whatever extension you want with `\input`; if you don't provide one, `.tex` is implied.